# How to delete an HTML table row that's generated by php and sql using checkboxes

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-server, checkbox

I am trying to delete -- using checkboxes -- an HTML table row/s populated by SQL data using PHP. I am new to this, so I would appreciate any improvements to my code. (especially SQL-injection, which I read quite a few times while researching)

**Part of HTML with a table - inv_main.php**

```
...
<div class="mid">
    <h1>Inventory</h1>
        <div class="content">
            <!-- buttons -->
                <div class="inv_btn">
                    <a href="add_form.php" type="button">Add</a>

                    <!-- button to press to delete ticked checkboxes -->
                    <form action="inventory.php" method="post">
                        <input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete"/>
                    </form> 

               </div>

            <!-- TABLE -->
                <div id="inv_tbl">                  
                    <table class="table table-striped" id="tblSearch">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Product Name</th>
                                <th>Supplier Name</th>
                                <th>Category</th>
                                <th>Unit Price</th>
                                <th>Retail Price</th>
                                <th>Est. profit per unit</th>                     
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                            <?php foreach($allInfo as $info): ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> <?= $info['product'] ?> </td>
                                    <td> <?= $info["supplier_name"] ?> </td>
                                    <td> <?= $info["category"] ?> </td>
                                    <td>$ <?= $info["unit_price"] ?> </td>
                                    <td>$ <?= $info["retail_price"] ?> </td>
                                    <td>$ <?= number_format(($info["unit_price"] - $info["retail_price"]), 2) ?></td>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[<?= $info['product'] ?>"] id="checkbox[]" value="<?= $info['product'] ?>" method="post"/></td>

                                </tr>
                            <?php endforeach ?>    
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
              </div>
        </div>
</div>
...
```

**PHP - inventory.php**

```
<?php
    /**
     *  inventory.php
     *  configures the inventory page.
     */

    // configuration
    require("../includes/config.php");
    require("../includes/render_dash.php");

    // if user reached page via GET...
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET")
    {
        // get all the info from the inventory database
        $allInfo = [];
        $getInfo = query("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id = ?", $_SESSION["id"] );
        foreach($getInfo as $info)
        {
            $allInfo[] = [
                "product" => $info["product"],
                "unit_price" => number_format($info["unit_price"], 2),
                "retail_price" => number_format($info["retail_price"], 2),
                "supplier_name" => $info["supplier_name"],
                "category" => $info["category"],
            ];
        }


        // render HTML
        render("inv_main.php", ["title" => "Inventory", "allInfo" => $allInfo ] );
    }
```

Note the 'form' right after the comment `<!-- button to press to delete ticked checkboxes -->` and the last table data inside the tbody tag.

I already saw similar questions but I still can't figure it out. If it helps, my PRIMARY KEYS in the inventory database are the user's `id` and `product`. The `id` is used for the `$_SESSION`, so using that would delete all the inventory data for, say user id #30 so I'm trying to reach the product, which is a string.

Comment: While this question is ok you can improve it by adding your errors if any or what's not working the way it was intended to. please read How to ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask And How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @davejal Is it okay to say I don't know how to go about solving the problem..? I mean I tried but I hit the brick wall on this one..

Comment: No, I wouldn't say that, but we need something more to work with. Errors your getting might be a good place to start if any or unexpected behaviour. i.e. you want a to happen but b happens.